# eBay API issues - cannot publish an offer

Tags: ebay-api

All of the following is being performed in eBay's API sandbox.

I am attempting to list an item by using the inventory API.  Specifically, I have created an inventory item and a relevant offer for that item.  When I make a POST request to the publish offer endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{
   "errors": [
     {
       "errorId": 25016,
       "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
       "subdomain": "Selling",
       "category": "REQUEST",
       "message": "The title value is invalid. Seller Provided Title Value is missing."
     },
     {
       "errorId": 25002,
       "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
       "subdomain": "Selling",
       "category": "REQUEST",
       "message": "A user error has occurred. The duration \"GTC\" day(s) is not available for this listing type, or invalid for category \"49996\".",
       "parameters": [
         {
           "name": "0",
           "value": "GTC"
         },
         {
           "name": "1",
           "value": "49996"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

I can't see any reference in any of the API documentation to a "Seller Provided Title".  The duration error is also confusing as the API says it only supports "GTC" listings.  The product has a title so it must be in reference to something else.

My inventory item is as follows:

```
{
   "sku": "13725",
   "product": {
     "title": "Harley Davidson bike",
     "aspects": {
       "Year": [
         "2016"
       ],
       "Model": [
         "Road Glide Special"
       ],
       "Manufacurer": [
         "Harley-Davidson®"
       ],
       "Type": [
         "Touring"
       ],
       "For Sale By": [
         "Dealer"
       ],
       "Vehicle Title": [
         "Clear"
       ],
       "Mileage": [
         "13393"
       ],
       "VIN (Vehicle Identification Number)": [
         "1HD1KTM10GB627264"
       ],
       "Color": [
         "Black Quartz"
       ]
     },
     "description": "Item description goes here",
     "imageUrls": [
"https://dw4i9za0jmiyk.cloudfront.net/2018/01/12/pre_ic60e5df584b870c3d2a55c86800eede_70618b24eb08.jpg"
     ]
   },
   "condition": "USED_EXCELLENT",
   "availability": {
     "pickupAtLocationAvailability": [
       {
         "quantity": 1,
         "merchantLocationKey": "425",
         "availabilityType": "IN_STOCK",
         "fulfillmentTime": {
           "value": 1,
           "unit": "DAY"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

And my offer object is as follows:

```
{
   "offerId": "5852159010",
   "sku": "13725",
   "marketplaceId": "EBAY_MOTORS",
   "format": "FIXED_PRICE",
   "availableQuantity": 0,
   "pricingSummary": {
     "price": {
       "value": "18294.0",
       "currency": "USD"
     }
   },
   "listingPolicies": {
     "paymentPolicyId": "5807565000",
     "fulfillmentPolicyId": "5806186000"
   },
   "categoryId": "49996",
   "merchantLocationKey": "425",
   "tax": {
     "applyTax": false
   },
   "status": "UNPUBLISHED",
   "eBayPlusEligible": false
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues on sandbox, and came to the conculsion it was broken.
They also have some limits on only certain categories working.

Have you tried it agains the live API, I have found this to be far more reliable, ignoring the fact doing development work live is dangerous!

For your info here is my working code offer:

```
    inventory_template = {
                "availability": {
                    "shipToLocationAvailability": {
                        "quantity": product.quantity_available
                    }
                },

                "condition": "NEW",
                "product": {
                    "aspects": {spec.name: [spec.value] for spec in product.specifics},
                    "brand": product.product_brand,
                    "description": product.product_description,
                    "imageUrls": [
                        "https://ebay.mydomain.co.uk/{}".format(img.image_link) for img in product.images],
                    "mpn": product.product_mpn,
                    "title": product.product_title,
                    "upc": [
                        product.product_upc,
                    ],
                    "ean": [
                        product.product_ean,
                    ],
                    # "epid": "string"
                },
                "sku": sku,
            }

    offer_body = {
            "availableQuantity": offer.available_quantity,
            "categoryId": offer.category_id,
            "listingDescription": html,
            "listingPolicies": {
                "paymentPolicyId": offer.payment_policy_id,
                "returnPolicyId": offer.return_policy_id,
                "fulfillmentPolicyId": offer.fulfillment_policy_id,
            },
            "merchantLocationKey": offer.merchant_location_key,
            "pricingSummary": {
                "price": {
                    "value": offer.summary_price_value,
                    "currency": offer.summary_price_currency
                }
            },
            "sku": offer.sku,
            "marketplaceId": offer.marketplace_id,
            "format": offer.format
        }
```

the `offer.available_quantity` etc are items from my database, its the structure I'm showing.

Comment: Maybe try listing the item(s) through the Trading API first.  After successfully listed, then use the Inventory API call `bulkMigrateListing` to convert the listing from Trading API managed to Inventory API managed.  Then all the price/stock updates can be done in bulk from Inventory API.